# How to cut medium format film for scanning and archival storing

Tags: nikon, film, storage, scanning, film-scanner

I shoot both 6x6 and 6x7 formats. There are no problems with 6x6 - I cut it as 3,3,3,3 frame pieces to fill a 4-row sleeve and have no problem scanning them in my Nikon 9000. However, if I cut 6x7 film using 3,3,2,2 scheme I'm in trouble:

- 3 frame pieces barely fit a sleeve row (can live with it though)
- I don't know how to scan the 3rd frame because the scanner only detects first two (offset
  doesn't help for 3rd frame)

I found a workaround though; I select film type as 6x9 and use positive offset so the last frame on film fits 2nd 6x9 frame of the scanner and then crop. It's unhandy (have to guess the offset) but I don't want to cut a film as 2,2,2,2,2 and waste an extra sleeve for storage. What would you recommend?

Comment: **WHY DO YOU CUT THEM! Try another way to scan them, take a picture of the negative against a background!**

Comment: Not sure I understand. How can you scan uncut 120 film with Nikon 8000/9000? Especially using FH-869S 869 S holder?

Comment: I think Rafael is assuming you are cutting the pictures (perhaps to fit into a 35mm scanner?) rather than cutting the film strip between frames. 6x7 is a problem format; you couldn't get an 8x10 contact sheet out of a roll cleanly either, it had to be 9 frames on one sheet with a frame left over. I doubt you'll find a solution that doesn't involve a leftover frame.

Comment: For storing I do 2 per row. This bleeds over into another sheet but that's not a huge problem for me, I just mark the two sheets accordingly, e.g. 2015 - 6 - A, 2015 - 6 - B. You can fit all the shots on a single 8x10 contact sheet as well you just have to put one row vertical (I don't contact with the film in the sleeve so I can arrange the strips as described).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wasting a sleeve is the right way to go unfortunately. If you're extremely careful yes they will barely fit in as 3s, but I've found that they'll slip out one edge and damage your film if you breath wrong.

Definitely do not go with an internegative (rephotographing your negatives) process, I'm not sure where that came from.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, there is wider sleeving that will hold four strips of 3 6x7s, such as [this sleeving material.](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/43015-REG/Print_File_PF1204UB100_Archival_Storage_Page_for.html)

If the scanner only detects the first two frames, then after you've scanned the first two frames, maybe you can insert the film upside-down to get the scanner to detect the last frame, then rotate that scan afterward.

Comment: Print File oversized sleeves are great, I use them for 35mm negs to store my 37-38 frame rolls (with frames 0 and 00) in pages with 7 rows of 6 frames. I honestly don't know why anyone would decide to make 7 rows of 5 frames (that's not even a complete roll!) negative pages, but they seem to be pretty much a standard (does it have anything to do with contact printing and paper sizes?). The only disadvantage of oversized pages is that they require, well, an oversized binder/box, which is really hard to get outside of the US.